# Installed modules using conda, but still getting ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, conda, python-import, python-module, modulenotfounderror

(Am using macOS Big Sur 11.6.2)

The problem first started with cartopy, but moving on from that I also encounter the problem with rioxarray and xarray. All I can think is that it is because i've used conda to install them. I have previously installed modules with pip that are importing fine.

If I do `conda list`, then I can see all those modules, but importing them in both RStudio or Jupyter notebook gives me the infamous `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I have been able to see on the Anaconda Navigator application my different environments, and I can see that the modules are there in my base(root) environment. I have base (root), anaconda3, cartopyenv, test_cartopy_env (from many attempts at trying to solve the problem), but in terminal when I do `conda info --envs`:

```
# conda environments:
#
                         /Users/me/opt/anaconda3
base                  *  /opt/anaconda3
cartopyenv               /opt/anaconda3/envs/cartopyenv
test_cartopy_install     /opt/anaconda3/envs/test_cartopy_install
```

So i'm not sure why theres an extra anaconda3 environment in the Anaconda Navigator, but anywho, that is what i've done. I noticed that looking at my sys.path that the base environment wasn't there, so I appended `/Users/me/opt/anaconda3` to the list of paths (which is where i can see the wanted modules in the Anaconda Navigator), but still no success. And in any case, when I open that file on my finder, I can't find any of the modules, here is a list of the `/Users/me/opt/anaconda3` directory (which I think is the base directory):

```
Anaconda-Navigator.app
LICENSE.txt
bin
conda-meta
condabin
doc
etc
include
info
lib
libexec
licensing
man
mkspecs
org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist
phrasebooks
pkgs
plugins
python.app
qml
resources
sbin
share
shell
ssl
translations
```

So that's what i've tried and I'm not sure what else to do. I think Python is looking not where it's supposed to be. I'm not sure how to check this or remedy it.

Comment: You almost certainly have 2 Python installations.  Conda is using one and `pip` is installing in the other. Do `pip --version` to find out which installation it points at. Either do all installations in parallel, once in Conda and one with `pip`, or set all of your environments to use the same installation.

Comment: If you have a Mac with M1 then there are some libraries that have the exact issue you described because many libraries have compiled files for the Intel chip. Apple tries to fix those type of issues with the "Rosetta 2" but its not always works. Try using Python 3.9 and above, install the latest library versions and hope for the best. Also you can try working with the native python instaletion (not Anaconda) or with miniforge compiled to M1.

Comment: @BoarGules so "pip --version" says ```pip 22.1.2 from /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)```, and sys.version is ```3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 13:02:00)```. I've now run pip install cartopy, and pip3 install cartopy, with both saying "requirement already satisfied", and finally did the install recommended on the documentation for conda, and then tried to import cartopy and still ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: So I decided that there is something funky going on with the way that jupyter and Rstudio (the two places i was running my python code on) were accessing python (probably a different version of python that i was installing to). I didn't know how to fix this, and to be honest, couldn't be bothered, so I just uninstalled python and r and all things code and tried to get rid of it as much as possible and start from scratch. I had spent too long trying to understand it. I will only touch conda again in the future with the utmost care and caution.